# Why functions from wctype.h do not work without setlocale()?

Tags: c, glibc, wchar-t, setlocale, widechar

My setup: glibc 2.24, gcc 6.2.0, UTF-8 environment.

Consider the following example:

```
#include <wchar.h>
#include <wctype.h>
#include <locale.h>
int main(void)
{
  setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "en_US.UTF-8");
  wchar_t wc = L'я'; /* 00000100 01001111 */
  if (iswlower(wc)) return 0;
  return 1;
}
```

Compile and run it:

```
$ gcc test.c
$ ./a.out; echo $?
0
```

Now remove `setlocale()` and run again. The result is different:

```
$ gcc test.c
$ ./a.out; echo $?
1
```

Technically, `setlocale()` is not needed here, because functions from `wctype.h` work with wide characters, which have a fixed encoding. (It goes without saying that `setlocale()` is required if we want functions from `ctype.h` to work correctly with non-ASCII characters, and if we use character conversion functions from wchar.h - to set external encoding.)

Why the example doesn't work without `setlocale()`?

Comment: How else would it know which alphabet to use?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams ISO10646 - it is fixed for wide characters. https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Extended-Char-Intro.html

Comment: ISO 10646 does not name an alphabet.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Did you notice that I used `en_US.UTF-8`, but the symbol `я` is not from `en_US`, and it is classified correctly. So, no, ISO10646 *does* name the alphabet.

Comment: It is not part of the en_US alphabet, but it does have a defined collate in that language.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams if any alphabet has info from any other alphabet (as it follows from your last comment) - this confirms that there is no need to specify the alphabet separately.

Comment: [en_US](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=localedata/locales/en_US;hb=HEAD) inherits from [en_GB](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=localedata/locales/en_GB;hb=HEAD) which inherits from [i18n](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=localedata/locales/i18n;hb=HEAD) which does classify "я".

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams OK, but WHY specify the parameter which carries no information? All alphabets are inherited (according to your last comment) from a fixed all-inclusive alphabet. Moreover, this is the point of wide characters - to use *one* alphabet.

Comment: Using `<ctype.h>` does not require a call to [`setlocale()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/setlocale.html) — those functions must work in an implementation-defined manner as if `setlocale(LC_ALL, "C")` was called before the program starts. The same is true of the rest of the standard library. The only other defined value (in the C standard) is `""`, the empty string, which uses an implementation-defined locale.  POSIX defines `"POSIX"` as an alternative name too, but it is equivalent to `"C"`.  So, I disagree with your "It goes without saying" aside.

Comment: Wide characters let you use a unified set of characters, but still represent multiple overlapping alphabets. E.g. the English and Turkish alphabets have "i" and "I", but English considers them the same character while Turkish considers them different.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thanks, I will correct this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The C standard says:

> 7.25 Wide character classification and mapping utilities `<wctype.h>`
>
> ...
>
> The behavior of these functions is affected by the `LC_CTYPE` category of the current locale.

Moreover (5.2.1 Character sets)

> Two sets of characters and their associated collating sequences shall be defined: the set in
>   which source files are written (the source character set), and the set interpreted in the
>   execution environment (the execution character set). Each set is further divided into a
>   basic character set, whose contents are given by this subclause, and a set of zero or more
>   **locale-specific members** (which are not members of the basic character set) called
>   extended characters.

and then (7.19 Common definitions `<stddef.h>`)

> `wchar_t`
>   which is an integer type whose range of values can represent distinct codes for all members of the **largest extended character set specified among the supported locales**

So there may be many extended character sets, one for each locale. Thus, wchar_t encoding may be locale dependent, because an encoding is a mapping between a set of integer codes and a set of characters, and the latter is potentially locale dependent.

Given the above, `<wctype.h>` **must** be locale dependent. Otherwise the standard would have to mandate that there is a single locale independent extended character set.

In this particular example, the value of the wide character constant `L'я'` (some integer code) may or may not correspond to any member of the extended character set under C locale.

As for specific behaviour of gcc and glibc, they always use Unicode/ISO10646/UCS4 as the extended character set for simplicity, under any locale. However they do not classify extended characters under C locale because they don't have to, as the standard permits. (A wild guess follows) Full Unicode classification tables are large and programs that only need ASCII don't have to pay for their use.

Comment: I'm trying to understand the reasoning behind the standard. If unspecified, locale is `"C"`. So, if `setlocale()` is removed from the example in OP, it must work anyway, but it does not. What prevents `"C"` to inherit from `i18n`, while `"en_US"` inherits from `i18n` ? (see comment of IgnacioVazquez-Abrams to OP)